# How can I cast a Java class in Clojure?

Tags: java, casting, clojure

I would like to cast a clojure Java object (assigned with let*) to another Java class type. Is this possible and if so then how can I do this?

Update:
Since I posted this question I have realised that I do not need to cast in Clojure as it has no concept of an interface, and is more like Ruby duck typing. I only need to cast if I need to know that an object is definitely of a certain type, in which case I get a ClassCastException

Comment: Can you post some sample code to see what you want to achieve?

Comment: Since I posted this I realised that I don't need to cast unless I actually need to know the type of an object

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a `cast` function to do that in `clojure.core`:

```
user> (doc cast)
-------------------------
clojure.core/cast
([c x])
  Throws a ClassCastException if x is not a c, else returns x.
```

By the way, you shouldn't use `let*` directly -- it's just an implementation detail behind `let` (which is what should be used in user code).

Answer (score 11):

Note that the `cast` function is really just a specific type of assertion.  There's no need for actual casting in clojure.  If you're trying to avoid reflection, then simply type-hint:

```
user=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
user=> (.toCharArray "foo")  ; no reflection needed
#<char[] [C@a21d23b>
user=> (defn bar [x]         ; reflection used
         (.toCharArray x))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:17 - reference to field toCharArray can't be resolved.
#'user/bar
user=> (bar "foo")           ; but it still works, no casts needed!
#<char[] [C@34e93999>
user=> (defn bar [^String x] ; avoid the reflection with type-hint
         (.toCharArray x)) 
#'user/bar
user=> (bar "foo")
#<char[] [C@3b35b1f3>
```

Comment: Actually your right, I realised quite soon that since there are no notions of interfaces that casting isn't needed