# How to avoid "illegal reflective access" warning in Clojure interop. (Cast?)

Tags: clojure

Although I believe I have a solid beginner's understanding of Clojure, I am fairly at sea when interoperating with Java.

Thus I am struggling to fix some (unavoidable) interop code that generates JVM warnings. This is the code, it takes a W3C dom node and creates an LS serializer from it so I can spit out the corresponding XML string:

```
(defn serializer
  [node]
  (let [serializer (-> node
                       .getOwnerDocument
                       .getImplementation
                       .createLSSerializer)]
    (.setParameter (.getDomConfig serializer) "xml-declaration" false)
    serializer))
```

The code works fine and did not result in warnings until a recent system update.

But JVM (for openjdk 11.0.10) does not seem to like  the call to `.getOwnerDocument` and it also does not like the call to `.getImplementation` as I discovered when I rewrote to avoid the call to `.getOwnerDocument`. The exact warning (arrows/linebreaks added):

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by clojure.lang.InjectedInvoker/0x00000008401e8040 
(file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.1/clojure-1.10.1.jar) 

-->to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.getOwnerDocument()<--

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of clojure.lang.InjectedInvoker/0x00000008401e8040
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

From [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315517/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-convert-an-xml-document-to-a-string-in-java-than) it appears casting should be involved in the call to `.getImplementation`, like so:

```
 DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
 LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();
```

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652675/how-can-i-cast-a-java-class-in-clojure) seems to indicate that casting is not needed in Clojure and you can avoid reflection by type hinting:

```
 (defn bar [^String x] 
         (.toCharArray x))
```

So I rewrote my function to use type hinting:

```
(defn serializer
  [^com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl node]
  (let [serializer (-> node
                       .getOwnerDocument
                       .getImplementation
                       .createLSSerializer)]
    (.setParameter (.getDomConfig serializer) "xml-declaration" false)
    serializer))
```

This seems to get me past warnings on `.getOwnerDocument` and `.getImplementation`. But now it's warning me about the call to `.createLSSerializer`, which is a bit frustrating as I seem to be calling this last method exactly and on the same type of object as the well upvoted answer I quoted from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315517/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-convert-an-xml-document-to-a-string-in-java-than) above. This is the error I get with the type hinting (arrows/linebreaks added):

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by clojure.lang.InjectedInvoker/0x00000008401e8040 
(file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.10.1/clojure-1.10.1.jar) 

-->to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDOMImplementationImpl.createLSSerializer()<--

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of clojure.lang.InjectedInvoker/0x00000008401e8040
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

If anyone has ideas on how to resolve this, or suggested areas for me to read up on in Java, I'd be very grateful. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the answer was to provide an additional type hint, like so:

```
(defn serializer
  [^com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl node]
  (let [serializer (-> node
                       .getOwnerDocument
                       ^com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDOMImplementationImpl
                       (.getImplementation)
                       .createLSSerializer)]
    (.setParameter (.getDomConfig serializer) "xml-declaration" false)
    serializer))
```

I discovered this thanks to a "related" question/answer Stackoverflow found and placed next to my question, [specifically these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765342/how-can-you-type-hint-within-the-threading-macro?rq=1). Apologies for not finding it earlier, perhaps this thread will provide some help if someone hits the same issue.

Comment: You could also avoid Illegal Reflective Access (and xerces reference) by using javax.xml.transform.Transformer for serialization. Get a TransformerFactory, make a DOMSource (give it the DOM node), set up a StreamResult (give a StringWriter), and "transform" source to result (with no actual XSL transformation).